# Fast convolution applicable;only circular or also linear/standard convolution?

Tags: fft, convolution

Fast convolution is the convolution performed using fft

Does fast convolution only works for circular convolution or also works for linear/standard convolution?

Comment: lacks reading of the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms) on the same topic, which will instantly lead you to the two dominant fast convolution algorithm articles, where your question is *very* explicitly answered. Man, don't dump your essay homework on us.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication in the frequency by itself implements circular convolution.

With proper zero padding and overlap management this can be extended to perform linear convolution as well. Google "Overlap Add" or "Overlap Save" for more info